# php session handling best practice and undefined issue

Tags: php, ajax, session, request

iam currently trying to build an admin panel but i have problem about handling sessions in php

my code basically depends on php and ajax request
so when a user load a page for example settings page
first i load session's through start_session() after the verification i close the session then i route to the page that requested by the user if the page has a submit (through ajax) i have to generate token for the request and store it in the session so i have to start new session again .
because when ever i open only when session at the beginning of the page and close it at the end i have an issue with multi requests (cuz of php session locking thing x.x)

but sometime when i open multi session through different part of the page i got issue of undefined session even though it's defined

what is the best practice here to handle like this situation

Answer (score 0):

Good morning.

I suggest you use Cookies  to store data as encrypted JSON. You will need decrypt that to test privilegies, but it's normal.

Comment: Store authentication data in a cookie?

Comment: Hi, Mr. @user3783243. Yes, You can encrypt them with openssl_encrypt function, or create a class who returns data encrypted, or decrypted. You store data on browser and spare memory on the host because you will don't use $_SESSION.